# Self hosted WCF with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, authentication

I've got a windows service, that hosts WCF service inside.
Below is definition of how endpoint is initialized:

```
WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceUrl"];
Uri baseAddress = new Uri(url);
Uri metadataAddress = new Uri(url + "Description");
CallService service = new CallService(controller);
ServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(service);

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (ICallService), binding, baseAddress);
host.Authorization.PrincipalPermissionMode = PrincipalPermissionMode.UseWindowsGroups;
ServiceDebugBehavior stp = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
stp.HttpHelpPageEnabled = true;

ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
smb.HttpGetUrl = metadataAddress;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
host.Open();
```

The problem is that when accesing this WCF service using computer name (e.g http://mycomputer.mydomain.int:4544/Somthing) first I receive an authentication window, and after it HTTP:400.

Everything works fine if accessing service using `http://localhost:4544/Something,` or if switch off Windows Authentication.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Event Viewer?

Comment: No I don't see any errors

Comment: Try workarounds from [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861).